# Why python autocompletion does not work if path to python binary is taken from variable?

Tags: external-command, plugin-you-complete-me

I use YouCompleteMe for python3 code completion, and when I have

```
let g:ycm_python_binary_path = '/usr/bin/python3'
```

in my `~/.vimrc` it works great. However, if I change it to

```
let python3path = system('/usr/bin/which python3')
let g:ycm_python_binary_path = python3path
```

It stops working. In both cases after vim startup the `:echo g:ycm_python_binary_path` shows `/usr/bin/python3`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all Unix commandline programs end their output with a trailing newline, and Vim's `system()` doesn't remove this.

This can be a difficult to spot with a regular `:echo`; the easiest way to check this from Vim is by piping the output to `hexdump`:

```
:echo system('/usr/bin/which python3 | hexdump -C')
00000000  2f 75 73 72 2f 62 69 6e  2f 70 79 74 68 6f 6e 33  |/usr/bin/python3|
00000010  0a                                                |.|
00000011
```

The last character (`0a`) is a newline ("\n").

There is no straight-forward way to dump the hex output of a Vim string like with `hexdump`; so if you want to check the value of a string then the easiest way is to output with a prefix and suffix; for example:

```
:let python3path = system('/usr/bin/which python3')
:echo 'X' . python3path . 'X'
X/usr/bin/python3
X
```

Notice how that second `X` is on a new line?

You can use something like this to remove the newline `python3path`:

```
:let python3path = system('/usr/bin/which python3')[:-2]
:echo 'X' . python3path . 'X'
X/usr/bin/python3X
```

which removes the last character (the `\n`) from the string that `system()` returns.

you could [`substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) it, which is guaranteed to work for strings that don't end with a `\n` at a (very) slight performance/readability cost:

```
:let python3path = substitute(system('/usr/bin/which python3'), "\n$", "", 0)
```